# How to make .PHP file only accessible to the server?

Tags: php, permissions

I created a cron job through goDaddy control center.

The cron job is in the folder "cron jobs".

I don't want anyone to be able to run it, how should I set the permissions of the folder so that it can't be publicly opened but it still can be used for the cron job?

Will unchecking Public > Read be enough to prevent anyone from running it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just put the files outside of the webroot/document root folder.

Comment: But that would also be required when the files were inside the doc root, right?

Comment: thanks, it cannot be done with permissions or other way right? I'm just asking since this cheap hosting seems to oblige me to keep a domain linked to the root.

Comment: It can be done by permissions, and maybe by .htaccess if your host supports it. But if they are that strict, I can hardly imagine they allow you to change the permissions.

Comment: outside of /public_html

Answer (score 5):

In .htaccess add this.

```
<Location /cronjobs>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

I included allow from 127.0.0.1 so it can be run from the server, i.e. so the cron can still run.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a directory, and in that directory create a file called `.htaccess` with this inside:

```
<FILESMATCH "\.php$">
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</FILESMATCH>
```

Now only the server can access PHP files inside that directory. Example, by `include` or `require`.

This is useful for keeping your MySQL password safe, you can put the connection function inside a PHP file in this "protected" directory and include it into your scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution if the file is meant to be used exclusively as an `include()` and not ran standalone by a user who enters it in the url.

Place this code at the top of the file you want to block direct calling of.

```
if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'blockedFile.php')
    {
    header('Location: ./index.php');
    exit();
    }
```

PHP checks if the file's name is the one being ran directly.  If blockedFile.php were included in index.php with `include()` then `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` would equal index.php. If it were standalone, it would equal blockedFile.php and send the user back to the index page.

Answer (score 1):

One option that you have is to use the $_SERVER values to see if it is a web request or a cli request.

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

I would look at checking to see if the `$_SERVER['argv']` value is set at the start of your script(s). If it's not set then exit the script.

Alternatively you can check to see if `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` is set, which would mean it's being executed by the webserver.

Note that I don't have a godaddy account handy to test this, so ensure you verify before going live.