# Is there something like WEB-INF in php web application?

Tags: php, web-applications, web-inf

I know about java based web applications directory structure. A simple web application will have something like this:
web-application folder
    WEB-INF folder
        under WEB-INF you can have your lib, class and all.

anything which should be publicly available will be kept outside WEB-INF and which  should not be directly accessible will be kept inside WEB-INF. If any file is present inside WEB-INF, it will be accessible only to java classes or jsp. User can not access the files which is present inside the WEB-INF directly through the browser. So, here WEB-INF works like a barrier, right.

Now, my question is, i am new to php and i want something like WEB-INF here. Is there any way to do so?? or how php based web applications protect their private files from direct access??
Thanks

Comment: What you want is not "something like WEB-INF", what you want is to make files not publicly accessible. Therefore: possible duplicate of [How to make .PHP file only accessible to the server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189337/how-to-make-php-file-only-accessible-to-the-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can place the PHP files where ever you would like to, and you can restrict access to the files directly by placing them in a folder (named whatever you like) and using .htaccess files to prevent users from accessing that folder directly (even if they were to access a PHP file directly, it would show a blank screen and not execute anything if all of your functions / classes are in these files only... likewise, they cannot in any ways access any of your PHP code as it's all server-side and only displays content you want it to output).

I have also heard of people putting some files in a folder above the http_docs/ or www/ folder so that the file and even the entire folder cannot be accessed at all from the website.

So, I would look up .htaccess files (and learn more about PHP!). Set up some PHP files that have functions in them and visit that page in your web browser and view the source, etc...

Comment: "I have also heard of people putting some files in a folder above the http_docs/ or www/ folder so that the file and even the entire folder cannot be accessed at all from the website."  That's the preferred way. What if Apache craps out and the htaccess rules don't apply?  What if he's not using Apache?  So on.